# How to update items in a list view after modifiying the array

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Im currently working with a list view in a fragment using a custom array adapter to take the name and amount of certain product. The thing is, when I have an item on the list view, and want to delete it, I use an OnItemLongClickListener to show an alert dialog asking for confirmation. After that, if the user confirmed action, I delete the value from the data base followed by deleting it from the array list.

Here's the deal whenever I delete the item from the list, it keeps showing int the fragment, it only updates once I leave the current page; The item is not there, you cant interact with it, but it's still visible.

Im using the notifyDataSetChanged function after deleting the item from both Db and array.

Here's the code:

Alert.Dialog:

```
public class DeleteDialog extends DialogFragment {
static int deleteSelected;
static CustomArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_image)
            .setTitle("Eliminar")
            .setMessage("¿Confirmar eliminación?")
            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                    deleteStockDialog(deleteSelected);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}

public static void setDeleteSelected(int i) {
    deleteSelected = i;
}
public static void setArrayAdapter(CustomArrayAdapter adapter){
    arrayAdapter=adapter;
}

public void deleteStockDialog(int selected) {
    ArrayList<Product> arrayProduct = DataBaseHub.getProductArrayList();
    Product newProduct = arrayProduct.get(selected);
    arrayProduct.remove(selected);
    MainView.dbHandler.deleteProduct(newProduct.getProductName());
}
```

}

Here's the fragment with the list view

```
public class StockPage extends Fragment {

private CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Product> arrayProduct;
private ListView listView;
private AddStockDialog addStockDialog;
private DeleteDialog deleteDialog;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    arrayProduct = MainView.baseHub.getProductArrayList();
    int layout;
    if (arrayProduct.isEmpty()) {
        layout = R.layout.empty_view;
    } else {
        layout = R.layout.stock_fragment;
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);

    if (layout == R.layout.stock_fragment) {
        //not empty
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView_Stock);
        adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getContext(), arrayProduct);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        dialogOnClick();
        dialogOnLongClick();
    } else {
        //empty
        listView = view.findViewById(R.layout.empty_view);
    }
    return view;
}

private void dialogOnClick() {
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            addStockDialog = new AddStockDialog();
            AddStockDialog.setAddSelected(position);
            addStockDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Añadir");
            //add to sell or stock
        }
    });
}

private void dialogOnLongClick() {
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            deleteDialog = new DeleteDialog();
            DeleteDialog.setDeleteSelected(position);
            DeleteDialog.setArrayAdapter(adapter);
            deleteDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Eliminar");
            //delete addStockDialog
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Bonus question, I tryed to use the listView.setEmptyView, but did nothing so I had to use the condition you see on top.

What I want to get is that whenever I delete an item, the listview somehow refreshs and shows only the active items or the blank screen if there are none left. 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: The arraylist used is static, I wanted to make sure I was working always with the same arrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove it from the adapter as well.

```
public void deleteStockDialog(int selected) {
    ArrayList<Product> arrayProduct = DataBaseHub.getProductArrayList();
    Product newProduct = arrayProduct.get(selected);
    arrayProduct.remove(selected);
    arrayAdapter.remove(newProduct);
    MainView.dbHandler.deleteProduct(newProduct.getProductName());
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thats an static array list, my bad; I mean the DataBaseHub array list gotten from the method is an static one

Comment: Having a static adapter that can have its list modified wouldn't be very recommended. There is a work around where you could declare a new arrayAdapter every time, but I wouldn't say that's the best practice. Not sure if this is helping you, but let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that

```
MainView.baseHub.getProductArrayList();
```

returns to you another instance of `ArrayList`, so when you remove the item from the new ArrayList it is still present into the `ArrayList` of the adapter.

You must remove your item from the ArrayList passed to the Adapter.

Otherwise create a new adapter and assign it to the Listview. It should force the recreation of the view

**UPDATE**

I think the problem is due to the DialogFragment that coming in foreground disable your fragment's view updating. Try to call notifyDatasetChange from inside your fragment, not inside your DialogFragment. For example you can set a boolean and in the onResume of the fragment you can check with that boolean if it must update view and in that case call notifyDatasetChange

Comment: The whole arraylist used in the adapter is static, what im saying is that, the item is deleted properly, the problem is that the listview in the fragment is not updating, so you can still see the item, but you cant interact with it

Comment: Have you tried to create a new adapter and to assign it to the listview? Sometimes it helps

Comment: The thing is, creating a new one, will not update the listview, because im already doing that by updating the existing one

Comment: but have you tried? it should be impossible because setAdapter should trigger view update. I have used this method a lot of time. Or maybe the problem is that static ArrayList?

Comment: It should not be a problem since, when im adding items its all good and dandy since its done from another activity, the problem is because im using an alert dialog executed in the same fragment that the updating is not working instantly, because when I swap to another fragment and come back it loads up properly